# SQL Server execute command Timeout exception after 30 sec

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, visual-studio-2010

Now i try to execute select statement from Winform to get large amount of rows from SQL Server DB it take 60 sec then retrieved data successfully. as on another environment i've timeout exception after 30 sec.

I don't use Command.CommandTimeout in query;
Is there is SQL Configuration or Network Configuration problem ?!

Comment: It is useful if you add the code that you are working on into the question to give context to your question.

Comment: default timeout is 30sec if i remember correctly. set it to 0 which means unlimited

Comment: generally, you should not alter the default timeout configurations, yet you should check your sql statement of why it is taking this long time, try adding some indexes and/or trace your query's execution plan. It would be great to post your select statement.

Answer (score -2):

Append 'Timeout=60;' in your connection string in web.config file.

for example:

```
"Data Source=**;Initial Catalog=**;Timeout=60;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=**;Password=**"
```

Comment: I need to know why there is timeout exception in first environment and another environment not ?!!  Both with same code and same connection string

Comment: @Partik Galoria You have to check the configuration of both environment.I myself have faced this issue . In production, the query were taking more time and in Dev, it was running fine. So, finally we found configurations differences between the two environments.